# Xcode 7 - Code completion not working with CGRectMake while initializing UIView/UILabel/UIButton in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

The auto code completion function doesn't work with my Xcode 7 when I try to type `CGRectMake` within the initialization of `UIView`, `UILabel`, `UIButton`, etc. If I press the **[esc]** key, the "No Completions" message is displayed:

[image: Autocompletion with CGRectMake]

The solution of deleting `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` doesn't work.

The code completion function still works perfectly at all other places. The only problem I see is with the above UI initializing condition.

This problem does not exist with my Xcode 6.4. Is it possible to be resolved with Xcode 7?

Comment: It's a bug in Xcode 7, still not fixed.

Comment: @EricD's comment is correct, it is still broken.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it's looks like bug or something else. I have Xcode 7.3 and code completion still don't work. But if i write the code to constructor it works and Xcode even don't show any syntax errors. If you still need code completion use variable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I too have the same issue. Sometime when the code is not running, it is giving auto code but not always. It might be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can kind of "fix" this problem by avoiding it.
These "XXXMake..." geometry utility functions incl. CGRectMake are outdated.

Try instead typing " CGRect( ".... you should get the new swift like signatures.